# How can I change pdf page color on Android?

Tags: applications, pdf, color

I downloaded a few ebooks in pdf and I want to change the white pages to a color easier on my eyes. Adobe Acrobat's accessibility options seem to be missing on Android and I don't like inverted/night mode. Which apps let you change page color when reading pdf on your phone?